# h3 has scrolling behavior

Tags: html, css

For some reason my `h3` element wants to scroll. I've tried testing and it appears to be in this code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.model-detail-caption {
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 4px solid var(--accent);
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="model-detail-caption">Some Text</h3>
```

Comment: Inspect your element (if using chrome) and copy in all the css that is effecting the element to your question.

Comment: Wait, by scrolling do you mean that it stays at the bottom of the page?

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 20px;

will cause this behaviour.

Comment: (@ChristopherKarlsson Firefox Safari and Edge (and even IE) have inspectors too, not just Chrome)

Comment: @ChristopherKarlsson Please post that as an answer so I can mark it answered. I had a `line-height: 1;` somewhere in my stylesheet

Comment: @StephenP I'm aware, I clarified because I don't know what the option to inspect elements is called in other browsers so the specification was an attempt to avoid any confusion on what tool is used.

Answer (score 0):

position: absolute; bottom: 20%; left: 20px; will cause this behaviour.